# clustering set of string sentences into unknown number of groups

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I have a set of sentences (each sentence = x number of rows where x belongs to range (1,6)). I want to group these sentences based on the similarities between them. I have tried fuzzy wuzzy.token_set_ration but the trouble I have is that I need to give it two sentences but I do want to iterate over combination of all sentences in the set if the set contains e.g. 10k sentences. How to group the data wisely? Is there any approach such as clustering to this problem? (I can have e.g. 9500 similar sentences.

example:

```
AAA Limited
AAA Ltd
AAA
Google
Gogle
Googlee
Facebook
Alphabet
Alpfabet
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

"Clustering" probably will mostly take you into the wrong direction.

What you seem to be looking for is *spelling correction*. You want to merge misspelled versions, and for that the best strategies are usually to transform the strings into a "phonetic" version (to find strings that 'sound' easy to mix up, as in your Alphabet example!), as well as seemingly stupid approaches that sort all the letters and remove duplicates - then both Google and Goolge and Goglee and Googlee become "eglo" and can be matched.

But I doubt you'll find anything that works reliably *automatically*, instead be prepared to require human interaction. (In above matching, Lego would also become eglo, and hence match Google. Maybe it's better to keep the first letter, and only apply it to the remainder).